# Negatives with "&" and "|" in data.tables "i" argument

Tags: r, data.table

I'm struggling a little bit to get my head around issues like this:

```
library(data.table)
testData <- data.table(id1 = c("a","b","c"),
                   id2 = c("b", "a", "c"))
```

Say I want the first and second row because I'm interested in "a". I can do this very intuitively with:

```
testData[id1 == "a" | id2 == "a"]
```

or

```
testData[(id1 == "a" | id2 == "a")]
```

Still very intuitively, I can not do this:

```
testData[id1 == "a" & id2 == "a"]
```

because the & operator wants condition 1 AND 2 to be true at the same time, which is never the case. Now, consider negatives. I want to exclude rows based on the exact same filter (no "a"s). I can do this with:

```
testData[!id1 == "a" & !id2 == "a"]
```

Here, the & operator apparently does not look for condition 1 is true AND condition 2 is true. Instead, it seems to operate like a "|" asking if one of the two is true. The analogue to the version above where an empty data.table was returnes would be:

```
testData[!(id1 == "a" & id2 == "a")]
```

Because here, no row fulfills both conditions at the same time. I don't understand why I need to use a bracked for negatives but not for positives. I'm probably misunderstanding something intuitively. In the same line, why does this:

```
testData[!id1 == "a" | !id2 == "a"]
```

not provide the same result? This here:

```
testData[!(id1 == "a" | id2 == "a")]
```

does, however.

**TLDR;**

Why is

```
testData[id1 == "a" & id2 == "a"]
```

the same as

```
testData[(id1 == "a" & id2 == "a")]
```

but

```
testData[!id1 == "a" & !id2 == "a"]
```

not the same as

```
testData[!(id1 == "a" & id2 == "a")]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:data.table]. This is simply [R Operator Precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) issue.The first two cases are exactly the same and the parenthesis not playing any role as they are outside. In the last two case you change the order of operations with the parenthesis. R order is `==` , `!`, `&`. In the fourth case you are switching the order (using the parenthesis) to `==`, `&`, `!`. Again, nothing to do with [tag:data.table]. Next time please add the [tag:r] tag to R related questions if you want to get noticed.

Comment: I think it is best to think of these things in terms of logic. "It is not the case that *both* id1 and id2 equal a" which is different from "Both id1 and id2 are different from a"

Comment: you are completely right, thanks! What should I do with the question now? Delete or do your want to post your comment as an answer? Should I delete the data.table tag?